# Timepicker on the click of an icon

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have included the timepicker and I am getting the option to select the time on its click.

```
//= require bootstrap-timepicker 

$('.timepicker-default').each(function(i) {

  //alert($(this).val());
  $(this).timepicker(
  {
    defaultTime:  $(this).val()
  });

});
```

Now if I add twitter-bootstrap icon 'icon-time' how can I get the option to select the time on its click?
I have used this:

```
 <div class="input-append bootstrap-timepicker-component">
  <input type="text" class="timepicker-default" name="planned_start_time" value="<%= @planned_start_time.nil? ? (Time.now).strftime('%I:%M%p') : @planned_start_time%>"> 
    <span class="add-on">
      <i class="icon-time"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

But my icon is coming outside and I am not able to select the time on the click of icon. The same thing is used in http://jdewit.github.com/bootstrap-timepicker/. But there we are able to select the time.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of the component. The markup has changed a little. The default functionality will do what you are wanting.
//js

```
$('.timepicker-default').timepicker();
```

//html

```
<div class="input-append bootstrap-timepicker">
    <input type="text" class="timepicker-default" name="planned_start_time" value="<%= @planned_start_time.nil? ? (Time.now).strftime('%I:%M%p') : @planned_start_time%>"> 
    <span class="add-on">
        <i class="icon-time"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```